# SQL Indexes - Am I using them correctly?

Tags: sql

I have a DB with a number of different tables that record the data of my users. Users are identified on the php backend by their unique userID, and this is used to identify who the owner of various records. So, for example, in a table called Budgets, I have:

budgetid | owner | budget_name | etc | etc

Whenever a user creates a new budget, the entry is assigned a unique primary on budgetid and their userID is inerted under "owner".

Given a lot of data searching takes place on the owner column (SELECT WHERE), that is presumably a sensible column on which to assign a non-unique Index?

Comment: If you want suggestions on how to tune one or more queries, then you should show us exactly what those queries are.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are on a good path. What you are describing is a foreign key. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key

I think you have the big picture. A few small things which might help...

It's a best practice to have foreign key column names conform to a standard of ending in _id, and using the tablename when you can. In this case, I would recommend you rename 'owner' to 'user_id'. It makes it a bit more clear that it contains the id from another table, and which table it is.

You should define the foreign key in your migration. Making the database aware of it will allow it to help enforce data integrity for you.

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Depending on your database, you might be able to add an index to speed up those searches you are referencing by adding

```
$table->index('email');
```

although some research before you do this for your specific database solution would be good. Mysql, for example, automatically adds an index when you add the foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 0):

> Given a lot of data searching takes place on the owner column (SELECT WHERE), that is presumably a sensible column on which to assign a non-unique Index?

Yes.  If a column is used commonly in a `WHERE` clause, then it is a good candidate for an index:

```
create index idx_budgets_owner on budget(owner);
```

I would be inclined to add another column to the index, to also handle more specific sort criteria.  Perhaps:

```
create index idx_budgets_owner_createdat on budget(owner, createdat);
```

Of course, you should also declare `owner` as a foreign key to the `users` table.  In MySQL, foreign key declarations also create an index.  However, for most databases, you need a separate `index` statement.